# ansible how to get last 2 digit of number

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have question about how to convert a digit to string and then get last 2 number using filter

For string, it's easy to use like:

```
vars:
  string_1: 'abcd'
  number_1: 1234
```

For string, it's easy:

```
"{{ string_1[-2:] }}"
```

But for number then i have to convert to string first but it failed while templating.

```
"{{ number_1 | string | [-2:] }}
```

How can I achieve this in single line code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close the conversion in parenthesis. The index has higher precedence compared to the filter. (And index can't be  used as a filter, of course).

```yaml
msg: "{{ (number_1|string)[-2:] }}"
```

---

The only difference is that modulus `%` returns an integer. The tasks

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (number_1 % 100)|type_debug }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (number_1|string)[-2:]|type_debug }}"
```

give

```yaml
    "msg": "int"
    "msg": "str"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a modulus trick here:

```
{{ number_1 % 100 }}
```

The modulus dividing by 100 should yield the final two digits of any number input.